Whats this feature called and how to design it in Android studio
enter image description here
Whats this feature where we can select multiple options
Name of the feature and code could be helpful       this feature  is useful i am not able to figure it out that how its build or whats it called

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md

The image contains chips in a chip group with multi-selection enabled. It can be implemented as:
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:singleSelection="false">

  <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
      android:id="@+id/chip_1"
      style="@style/Widget.Material3.Chip.Filter"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:checked="true"
      android:text="@string/text_filter_1"/>

  <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
      android:id="@+id/chip_2"
      style="@style/Widget.Material3.Chip.Filter"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/text_filter_2"/>

  <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
      android:id="@+id/chip_3"
      style="@style/Widget.Material3.Chip.Filter"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:checked="true"
      android:text="@string/text_filter_3"/>

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

Considering you are using Kotlin:
val checkedChipIds = chipGroup.checkedChipIds


To create selectable Chip components in Android that change text color when selected, follow these steps:
Add the Material Components Library: Ensure you have added the Material Components library to your build.gradle file.
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'

Create Color Selectors: Define color selectors for the chip background, stroke, and text colors.
res/color/chip_selector.xml:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/selectedChipBackgroundColor" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/unselectedChipBackgroundColor"/>
</selector>

res/color/chip_stroke_selector.xml:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/selectedChipStrokeColor" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/unselectedChipStrokeColor"/>
</selector>

res/color/chip_text_color_selector.xml:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/textColor"/>
</selector>

Define Colors in colors.xml:
res/values/colors.xml:
<resources>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="selectedChipBackgroundColor">#004c80</color>
    <color name="unselectedChipBackgroundColor">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="selectedChipStrokeColor">#004c80</color>
    <color name="unselectedChipStrokeColor">#004c80</color>
    <color name="buttonBackgroundColor">#004c80</color>
    <color name="textColor">#004c80</color> <!-- Define this color -->
</resources>

Define Styles for Chips:
res/values/styles.xml:
<resources>
    <style name="SelectableChip">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Define Button Background:
res/drawable/button_background.xml:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/buttonBackgroundColor"/>
    <corners android:radius="24dp"/>
</shape>

Update Your XML Layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectPurposeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Purpose"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/selectPurposeText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:singleSelection="false">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipCoffee"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Coffee"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipBusiness"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Business"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipHobbies"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Hobbies"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipFriendship"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Friendship"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipMovies"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Movies"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipDining"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Dining"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipDating"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Dating"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chipMatrimony"
            style="@style/SelectableChip"
            android:text="Matrimony"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_selector"
            app:chipStrokeColor="@color/chip_stroke_selector"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipTextColor="@color/chip_text_color_selector" />
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSaveExplore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="Save & Explore"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

This is how the UI will look like

